# Extract table from html table using bash

Tags: html, bash

Hello I've a problem with parsing the html table using bash script. I managed to take table but extracting the data is not going so well.
The table content looks like this:

```
<tr><td><small>1</small></td><td>Kalisz</td><td>62-800</td><td>Poland</td><td>Greater Poland</td><td>Kalisz</td><td>Kalisz<tr><td></td><td colspan=6>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/maps/browse_51.75_18.087.html" rel="nofollow"><small>51.75/18.087</small></a></td></tr>
<tr class="odd"><td><small>2</small></td><td>Piotrków Trybunalski</td><td>97-300</td><td>Poland</td><td>Łódź Voivodeship</td><td>Piotrków Trybunalski</td><td>Piotrków Trybunalski<tr class="odd"><td></td><td colspan=6>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/maps/browse_51.411_19.689.html" rel="nofollow"><small>51.411/19.689</small></a></td></tr>
<tr><td><small>3</small></td><td>Toruń</td><td>87-100</td><td>Poland</td><td>Kujawsko-Pomorskie</td><td>Toruń</td><td>Toruń<tr><td></td><td colspan=6>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/maps/browse_53.021_18.623.html" rel="nofollow"><small>53.021/18.623</small></a></td></tr>
```

There are 200 of those rows. My bash script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

URL="https://www.geonames.org/postalcode-search.html?country=PL&q="

HTML=$(curl -s "$URL")

(echo "$HTML" | grep -A 201 "<table class=\"restable\">" | tail -n 200 )>> table.html

html_lines=()
while IFS= read -r line; do
  html_lines+=("$line")
done < "table.html"

for html_line in "${html_lines[@]}"; do
  field1_value=$(echo "$html_line" | grep -oP '(?<=<td>)[^<]+(?=</td>)')
  field2_value=$(echo "$html_line" | grep -oP '[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}')
  field3_value=$(echo "$html_line" | grep -oP '(?<=<small>)[^<]+(?=</small>)')

  # Printing the extracted fields
  echo "$field1_value;$field2_value;$field3_value" >> output.txt
done
```

Current result I'm getting is:

```
Kalisz
62-800
Poland
Greater Poland
Kalisz;62-800;1
51.75/18.087
Piotrków Trybunalski
97-300
Poland
Łódź Voivodeship
Piotrków Trybunalski;97-300;2
51.411/19.689
Toruń
87-100
Poland
Kujawsko-Pomorskie
Toruń;87-100;3
53.021/18.623
```

And the result I want to have is:

```
Greater Poland;62-800;51.75/18.087
Łódź Voivodeship;97-300;51.411/19.689
Lesser Poland;33-300;49.609/20.704
```

I want to parse them for future use in csv file

Comment: Rather than parsing a formatted HTML, how about downloading a data file dedicated for export (https://download.geonames.org/export/dump/PL.zip in this case), and parse that. It would be much easier.

Comment: I know but I need this for my web-mining assigment @pmf hence this question

Comment: Shouldn't mining include all kinds of sources? But even when sticking to HTML, this is a structured format with a representation model that is not line-oriented. Thus, trying to destructure it by looping over its lines (which, admittedly, is the best Bash can do here) is the wrong track. You need a parser which lets you access the content logically. So, either focus on writing a generalized parser (i.e. not tailored to a specific web page), or use an existing one to extract the data you need.

Comment: Respectfully I agree, but the task is a task If I wanted to do something like this I would def choose better tool for a job. I just want to get this done and be over it :(

Comment: fwiw, `grep -A 201` and `tail -n 200` imply that you know beforehand the exact structure of the downloaded file and the number of entries in the table, not to mention that you're assuming the downloaded html code is formatted in a pre-determined manner (eg, 'pretty' format with plenty of linefeeds);  while this pair of `grep / tail` command may get you the desired set of data for ***this*** particular download keep in mind this approach will (eventually) need to be replaced with a more dynamic approach

Comment: the 'simple' solution would be to pipe the `grep` outputs to additional code that captures the desired line of output; hint: replace the last line of the loop with something like `printf "######## 1\n%s\n##### 2\n%s\n##### 3\n%s\n" "$field1_value" "$field2_value" "$field3_value"` to see what each `grep` is generating; keep in mind this approach is going to be hardcoded for ***this*** specific set of data and likely won't be reusable for other 'web-mining assignments'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `perl` one-liner you could try following. Written and tested with your shown samples Only.

```
perl -pe 's/^<tr.*?>(?:<td>.*?<\/td>){2}<td>(.*?)<\/td><td>.*?<\/td><td>(.*?)<\/td>.*?<a href=".*?_(.*?)_(.*?)\.html.*$/$2;$1;$3\/$4/'  Input_file
```

Here is the [Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/reHpdh/1) of regex.

***Explanation of regex:***

```
^                   ##Matching from starting of the line here.
<tr.*?>             ##Matching from <tr till very next occurrence of > which will include class= line occurrence also.
(?:                 ##Creating a non-capturing group here.
   <td>.*?<\/td>    ##Matching <td> till very next occurrence of </td>
){2}                ##Matching 2 occurrences of it.
<td>(.*?)<\/td>     ##Matching from <td> till very next occurrence of </td> and storing values in between in 1st capturing group here.
<td>.*?<\/td>       ##Matching from <td> till very next occurrence of </td>.
<td>(.*?)<\/td>     ##Matching from <td> till very next occurrence of </td> and storing values in between in 2nd capturing group here.
.*?                 ##Doing Lazy match
<a href=".*?_       ##To make sure it matches very first occurrence of <a href=" till next occurrence of _
(.*?)_              ##Creating 3rd capturing group with Lazy match till next occurrence of _ here.
(.*?)               ##Creating 4th capturing group with a lazy match here.
\.html.*$           ##matching literal . followed with html till last of the line.
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Works for rest aswell

Comment: @Maqcel, Added detailed explanation for used regex in code, cheers and happy learning.

Answer (score 2):

Using any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="</td>"; OFS=";" }
{
    for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) {
        gsub("</?tr>|<td[^>]*>|.*<small>|</small>.*","",$i)
    }
    print $5, $3, $8
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
Greater Poland;62-800;51.75/18.087
Łódź Voivodeship;97-300;51.411/19.689
Kujawsko-Pomorskie;87-100;53.021/18.623
```

Answer (score 1):

If your rows are guaranteed to be on one line and there is no exception to the formatting compared to the example,

```
sed 's/<.td><td>/;/g;s/<[^>]*>//g;s/&nbsp;/ /g'
```

will give you a CSV version of the table that you can parse with `awk`.